# Sending POST Request to API Gateway via SST Console Returns 403: Forbidden Error

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm using the SST framework to run a serverless backend in AWS. The DB being used is DynamoDB, but I don't believe in this case that the Lambda function is even being triggered. From the SST console, I've attempted to trigger a POST request to a certain API route, but all I receive is a 403: Forbidden error. When I check my Cloudwatch logs, the only details provided are that it is a 403 error. I'm not really sure where the problem lies, but if it were to reach the lambda function or the DB, some kind of error would surely be logged in the cli or console.

I've tried deleting the stack and rewriting the routes, but it's to no avail. I'm currently using ElectroDB to help with single table design, so I've tried to troubleshoot possible entity issues. This doesn't seem to affect the issue either, because no ElectroDB errors are being thrown. I would expect that if any other parts of the stack were an issue, then they would throw an error in the cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue. The problem was that the SST console was not providing any error feedback so I was in the dark about what was going on. After using their cli tool to test the API, I found that there were formatting issues with the data being used in regards to the JSON.parse.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SST Permissions examples](https://docs.sst.dev/constructs/Permissions#examples) and make sure you've attached permissions to your app so it can communicate with AWS cloud services.

Comment: Okay, so I've looked through all the permissions examples, and it seems that my permissions are all good.